# No data available in first line of data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

After getting the data from firebase, the first line in the datatable is showing no data available.
How should I correct this?

I know I'm only using one data set but I try with 10 data it's still showing that there is no data available in the first line.

I tried everything I know but nothing works.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivx7R.png)

My js code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user_data').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',

        colums: [
            { title: "USN" }, { title: "Email" }, { title: "Name" }, { title: "Password" }
        ],
        targets: -1,
        className: 'dt-body-right',
        hover: 1,

    });
 });
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("StudentID");

 rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    
    USN = snap.child("UserUSN").val();
    Email = snap.child("Useremail").val();
    Name = snap.child("Username").val();
    Password = snap.child("Userpassword").val();


      $("#table-body-pengguna").append("<tr><td>" + USN + "</td><td>" + Email +
          "</td><td>" + Name + "</td><td>" + Password + "</td></tr>");
 })
```

My html code

```
    <body>
    <table id="user_data" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>USN</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Password</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="table-body-pengguna">

        </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: Inserting your own html rows into existing DataTable instance is wrong approach. Use the API methods to pass the data to the instance so it knows it exists.

Comment: thanks now its not showing the error

Comment: what do you get with console.log('rootRef',rootRef). I'm not familiar with firebase. Just looked at the documentation. What I see your code is right. You don't need to create the table blow. You have to make a json string instead. As mine in the example below. Look at the examples e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 1,
    ajax: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bmehler/employees/main/personal",
    "columns": [{
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "job"
      },
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Just try this small example.

Comment: Ya its working but i want it to connect with firebase can you able to provide me with a example of firebase connection Thanks for help